# Relational Database Reductions

Tags: relation-algebra

So In the study guide for our Db Design final, the professor gave us this Information preserving logical design, Where bold is a primary key and italics are a foreign key.

- L1: Donor: **D_ID**, D_Name, *[0, L1, 1]D_Spouse[0, N, 1], [1, L5, 1]D_CI_ID[1, C, 1]*
- L2: Non-Alumni: ***[1, L1, 3]NA_D_ID[1, u]***, NA_Gender, NA_RelDesc
- L3: Alumni: **A_UID**, A_Gender, A_Schnum, *[1, L1, 3]A_D_ID[1, u]*
- L4: Business:***[1, L1, 3]Bus_D_ID[1, u]***, Bus_Contact, Bus_MatchAmt
- L5: Contact_Info: **CI_ID**, CI_Address
- L6: Phone: **Ph_Number**, ***[0, L5, n]Ph_CI_ID[1, C, 1]***
- L7: Email: **EM_Address**, ***[0, L5, n]EM_CI_ID[1, C, 1]***

The problem that he wants us to solve is to  List any undesirable FD’s that need to be addressed through decomposition, and which normal form they violate.  Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Just as a start, what are FD's? and what is the normal form?